# Tag a link attribute data-image can't display value c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

I want using gallery thumbnail css and js from bootstrap snippet [Easy image gallery in modal](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/easy-image-gallery-in-a-modal). When I'm using control from c# it's cannot display.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" class="thumbnail" href="#" data-image-id="" data-toogle="modal" data-image='<%# Eval("Image") %>' data-target="#image-gallery">
    <dx:ASPxBinaryImage runat="server" class="img-responsive" ID="img" Eval='<%# Eval("Image")%>' Height="150px" Width="150px"></dx:ASPxBinaryImage>
</asp:HyperLink>
```

My data-image tag a link don't same show like `src` from tag img. A data-image value `System.Byte[]`

This make my modal show picture cannot display

[image]

Comment: I tried adding `ASPxBinaryImage` to ASPX page and getting warning `Attribute 'Eval' is not a valid attribute of 'ASPxBinaryImage'`. Is your `Eval` attribute correct? If your `Image` property is byte array of an image, `Eval` in `Hyperlink` control may execute `ToString` method to that array instead of reading its contents through byte stream, causing byte type name (`System.Byte[]`) is propagated to page instead of giving image URL string.

Comment: The attribute Eval have not problem. This is correct. This `ASPxBinaryImage` show image but when click to show modal it is not show an image. Yes it is from binary @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Certainly you've passing wrong value into `data-image` attribute - in the sample link provided it refers to relative path of image URL wanted to show with, but in your markup it passed binary content from byte array of target image - that's how it displays `System.Byte[]`. Try adding another string variable which passing relative path of image URL instead.